# Bluetooth communication between mobile app and Arduino (HC-06 module)

Tags: flutter, ionic-framework, arduino, bluetooth

I am currently working on an old legacy Ionic 3.0 (Angular) project. As it is near the 10 years of age, this app will be redone from the grounds up.

A central part of this project is the Bluetooth communication between the mobile app and an Arduino device which has an 'HC-06 Bluetooth Serial Transceiver Module'.

**Must #1 :** the new app has to be available for both : Android & iOS (hence using Ionic or Flutter).
**Must #2 :** the new app has to compatible with even the most recent (stable) versions of Android & iOS (obviously).

---

I have mainly identified two solutions, but they both have their (major) flaws.

**1) Ionic with the [Bluetooth Serial](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v5/native/bluetooth-serial) plugin.**

Seems to be somewhat of an "accepted" solution, and is also the plugin used in my legacy project. However, said plugin has not been maintained for **+5 years**. There is not guarantee it is compatible with recent versions of Android & iOS. For instance, there seems to be some problems with the way bluetooth permissions are handled in newer versions.

**2) Flutter with the [Flutter Bluetooth Serial](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bluetooth_serial) package.**

A more recently maintained package, but sadly currently only compatible with Android.

---

I have only very recently (since I started this project about 3 weeks ago) interested myself in IoT, BLE-Bluetooth, Serial-Bluetooth, HC Bluetooth Modules, ... and I have to admit I am still mixing things quite a lot.

But from what I understood, communication through an HC-06 module (or any HC module for that matter) has to be "serial". Meaning "BLE Bluetooth" plugins/packages cannot communicate with my module (hence why I'm looking for "Serial" plugins/packages only). But have I got all that right ?

I am really looking for any help, even if it means **completely** changing what I have :

- Should I work with something completely different from Ionic or Flutter ?
- Can any other Bluetooth plugin/package be used with some tweaks here and there ?
- Should I use a completely different Bluetooth Module ?

As I said, I am a real beginner to Arduino Bluetooth communication, so do please enlighten me if there are "major" things I am missing.

Thank you all very much in advance.
Myrmillion

Comment: The HC-06 Bluetooth module is not compatible with iOS devices. You will need a Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) module or an Arduino-compatible board with onboard BLE to work with both iOS and Android.  The HM-10 is an example of a readily available Bluetooth LE module.

Comment: I actually didn't know the HC-06 module itself wasn't compatible with iOS. Thanks a lot for warning me, I will definitely ask my uni to switch to BLE for this project !

That being said, it also means I won't be able to work and test till we receive the new BLE module (probably a few weeks), and I can hardly afford to "lose" more time.

Do you know if, for the time being, I could "simulate" the BLE connection some other way, so that I can already start working on this and just connect on the new module later ? I have 2 phones, laptops, ... at my disposal if that help. Thank you so much !

Comment: A phone can act as a BLE peripheral. For iOS search for CBPeripheralManager and you'll find examples. For Android, search for BluetoothGattServer.

Comment: Note that there is no serial Bluetooth protocol that works on both Android and iOS. If you need a serial protocol, you will need to design one over GATT, which is what thing like BluetoothSerial are trying to do. But, glancing over BluetoothSerial, I'm not sure it works correctly. I don't see anywhere that it chunks the data into MTU-sized blocks, which means that writes larger than about 20 or 250 bytes (depending on the hardware) will probably fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable inputs !